# Type Error - терминал, Python

Tags: python

бот стоит на VPS хостинге, но он вылетает, в терминале вот такой текст появляется, из-за чего это? Приложил конец кода. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    except Exception as e:
        raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка не в конце скрипта, а судя по выводу ошибки на 110 строке. И это происходит потому что после вызова `cur.fetchone()` нельзя обратится к [0]

Формально `object is not subscriptable` означает, что объект NoneType не реализует метод **getitem**(). [Подробнее](https://pythonz.net/references/named/object.__getitem__/)

Следовательно `cur.fetchone()` возвращает None

Измените логику, либо добавьте обработку исключения `try... except...` .